# access angular cookie in view

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angularjs-scope

I fill my angularjs cookie with some objects like

```
 $scope.benchmarks = function(product) {               
     $cookieStore.put("benchmark_prods", product);
     $scope.benchmarks = $cookieStore.get("benchmark_prods");
     console.log(benchmarks); //is getting filled
 };
```

than I would like to access in view if cookies contains elements but I don't know how

I tried

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products">
//here the click event which is stroing product in cookie an simultanly shuld update cookie loop
   <a data-placement="bottom" ng-click='benchmarks(product)' title="" rel="tooltip" class="button-icon jarviswidget-delete-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></a>
</div>

             <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                        <fieldset>
                            <section>
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <legend class="params">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            Benchmarks  
                                        </h4>                                            
                                    </legend>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-repeat="benchmark_prod in benchmarks">
                                    {{benchmark_prod}}

                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-group" id="conf_display">

                                </div>
                    </div>
```

but doesn’t work

Comment: first of all, look at your code. $scope.benchmarks is used two times. one as a function and one as scope variable. change second scope name.

Answer (score 1):

```
         $scope.benchmarks = function(product)
         {               
            $cookieStore.put("benchmark_prods", product);

            if($cookieStore.get("benchmark_prods")!=null &&  $cookieStore.get("benchmark_prods")!="")
            {
               $scope.benchmarkspro=$cookieStore.get("benchmark_prods")
            }

            console.log(benchmarkspro); //is getting filled
         };
```

change benchmarks to benchmarkspro in html.

Comment: I have problems to project the cookie in view not inside controller

Comment: Right. But view gets updated as you manipulate scope in controller. Try my code. I m sure your problem will be solved...

Comment: there is an event click if I click on specific product than the listing on cookies should be updated but doesn't work I will make an update on code